# Problems using dual monitors via Optimus and HDMI

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, multiple-monitors, 14.10, 15.10

Any idea what goes wrong with my dual monitor setup?

---

I've a notebook with Nvidia 525M graphics card and default Unity installed. With the Nvidia Optimus driver 352.63 and switched to the Nvidia card I get output using either the plugged in HDMI monitor or the internal notebook display.

[image]

When I try to use both monitors in parallel by expanding the desktop over both displays the windows manager goes crazy. It expands the desktop/window area over both displays but fails to increase the pixels to the sum of both displays:
[image]

And the nvidia-settings dialog does not show the correct pixels nor the HDMI monitor or something - Even when I use the HDMI device only (internal display deactivated):

[image]
[image]

Curious is also:

- Top panel is shown correctly.
- Mouse pointer is shown correctly - Of course you can't easily hit a button since it is misplaced on the screen image.
- The displays are correctly identified but their possible resolutions list are switched between displays.
- This happens in 14.10, 15.04 (upgraded) and 15.10 (upgraded).
- Using internal display and the same display from HDMI port connected to the VGA port instead the dual monitor setting works without any flaw! (Sadly this is not a solution since the display I will use in the future does not have a VGA port any more.)

I'm currently on 15.10 Ubuntu using Unity.

My `~/.config/monitors.xml` shows:

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="HDMI-0">
          <vendor>MAX</vendor>
          <product>0x089c</product>
          <serial>0x00000001</serial>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="LVDS1">
          <vendor>AUO</vendor>
          <product>0x129e</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
      </output>
      <output name="VGA1">
      </output>
      <output name="VIRTUAL1">
      </output>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="LVDS1">
          <vendor>AUO</vendor>
          <product>0x129e</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
          <width>1600</width>
          <height>900</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="VGA1">
      </output>
      <output name="VIRTUAL1">
      </output>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
      <clone>no</clone>
      <output name="HDMI-0">
          <vendor>MAX</vendor>
          <product>0x089c</product>
          <serial>0x00000001</serial>
          <width>1680</width>
          <height>1050</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <rotation>normal</rotation>
          <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
          <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
          <primary>yes</primary>
      </output>
      <output name="LVDS-1-0">
          <vendor>AUO</vendor>
          <product>0x129e</product>
          <serial>0x00000000</serial>
      </output>
      <output name="VGA-1-0">
      </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.04, I could fix that issue by changing the display settings on Compiz. Have a look at [14.10 Dual Monitors are displayed as distorted single screen mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557149/14-10-dual-monitors-are-displayed-as-distorted-single-screen-mode/594922#594922)

On CompizConfig Settings Manager, go to "General Options", then "Display Settings" and do the following:

- Uncheck `Detect Outputs`
- In the Outputs array, set the resolutions of each of your screens. The numbers after the resolution `1920x1080+0+0` are the offset. It's important to add this offset according to your needs. I have two full HD screens, so I added the following configuration:

  - `1920x1080+0+0`
  - `1920x1080+1920+0`

The second output has an offset of 1920, because it is on the right side of the first output, which has a width of 1920.